# How to pass a looping variable into a regex?

Tags: javascript

```
var sourceArray = "un un un deux deux";
var termArray = ["un", "deux"];
var found = 0;

for (var i =0; i < termArray.length; i++) {
        found = sourceArray.match(/termArray[i]/g);
        document.write(found.length);
    }
```

In the above code, I try to have termArray[i] render corresponding string value from termArray. However this codes doesn't work. How to format termArray[i] in the match parenthesis so it's replaced by string value while looping ?

Also, where should I put the [i] in the document.write line to have it loop correctly.
Please try not to change the code too much even if it's not "optimum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a regular expression using strings you need to use the RegExp constructor rather than a RegExp literal:

```
var sourceArray = "un un un deux deux";
var termArray = ["un", "deux"];
var found = 0;

for (var i =0; i < termArray.length; i++) {
    found = sourceArray.match(new RegExp(termArray[i], 'g'));
    document.write(found.length);
}
```

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Aaa so this was about using the constructor instead of the literal. Thanks for your answer and all those who have answered. I'm surprised document.write(found.length); iterates correctly without specifying [i]. Why is that ?

Comment: @Benj You are replacing the value of `found` on each iteration, so it only contains the value for the current iteration and has no information about the other iterations.

Comment: Hmm when complementing the regexp to find exact string with ^ and $: such as in     found = sourceArray.match(new RegExp('\\^' +termArray[i]+'\\$', 'g')); which I believe is the correct syntax, it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null". Any clue why ? Tks

Comment: @Benj That is the expected behaviour when you try to access `found.length` when there were no matches. If you remove the `\\`s in your RegExp and set `sourceArray = "un";` you'll see that it writes a `1` before throwing the exception. To prevent the exception you can do what `vol7ron` did with the `|| [];` or you can just do a test like `if(found){ document.write(found.length); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `RegEx` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var exp = new RegEx('/' + i + '/');
    exp.test('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `RegExp` object, rather than using the regex inline:

```
for (var i =0; i < termArray.length; i++) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(termArray[i], "g");
    var found = sourceArray.match(pattern);
    document.write(found.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourceArray = "un un un deux deux";
var termArray   = ["un", "deux"];
var found       = 0;

for (var i=0,n=termArray.length; i < n; i++) {
   found = sourceArray.match( termArray[i], "g" ) || [];
   document.write(found.length);
}
```

---

1. Moved `termArray.length` into variable `n` for optimization via caching
2. You can pass two parameters to `match()`, the first a value, the second the modifiers; a regexp object should be generated from them internally
3. Added a `|| []` for conditions when no match is found so that `found.length` will return `0` and not break

Answer (score 0):

This should work with minimal changes:

```
var sourceArray = "un un un deux deux";
var termArray = ["un", "deux"];
var found = 0;

for (var i =0; i < termArray.length; i++) {
    found = sourceArray.match(new RegExp(termArray[i], "g"));
    document.write(found.length);
}
```

However a small improvement could be:

```
var matches = sourceArray.match(new RegExp(termArray.join('|')), 'g');
```